# Create a script that output safari version

Tags: bash, macos, variables, safari

Im trying to create a script that check the version of safari.

If its lower the 10.0 then do the rest of the script.

Im trying to save to a variable by: "default read" command result
but the output is blank ( echo is blank and the "if" doesnt work) the code Im using :

`Version= defaults read /Applications/Microsoft\ Word.app/Contents/Info CFBundleShortVersionString`

Comment: Can't you run something like `firefox --version`?

Comment: I tried that it doesnt work

Comment: maybe there is a way to do it with apple script or something?